# CreateJS Publish of Flash Project Flickers

Tags: flash, createjs

When I publish my Flash project as a CreateJS HTML5 file set the animation flickers. It seems to do it at the key frames.

It does not flicker when output as an .swf.

Thanks-in-advance,

Guido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateJS tool isn't perfect, there are few bugs when exporting flash animation to JS. Actually there are many bugs, mostly due to complexity of Flash animation. It could be one of many things - you're using complex tweens, your objects are grouped, mixed between type (movie clip, graphics), movieclips represented as graphics or the opposite. Well, to be fair most of these problems can be avoided by setting export options in the CreateJS window.

Please, upload the animation, the exported HTML and SWF files somewhere and provide a link, it will be a lot easier for me (and others who wants to help) to try exporting the animation and telling you exactly what's wrong.